# Textbox loses its value on button click in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have written a jquery code where I want the user to put some value in a textbox, and if user does not put any value, the user should be alerted with message to fill the textbox. The problem is that, when I put some value in textbox and submit the button the textbox loses its value and gives me the alert message. Please see the code for your reference. What should I do to prevent from losing its value.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSubmit').click(function () {
            if ($('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlGraduation').val() == 'Other' && $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtOther').val('')) {
                alert("Please specify your other education details");
                return false;
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do the below:

```
 && $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtOther').val('')
```

It resets the textbox. Remove that code. To check the emptiness, do this:

```
&& $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtOther').val() === ''
```

By this way, your full code becomes:

```
if ($('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlGraduation').val() == 'Other' && $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtOther').val() === '') {
```

**Clearing for the second time**

```
else {
    $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlGraduation').val()
    $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtOther').val()
    return true;
}
```

Comment: so, what should i do, Actually, If textbox value is empty or null, it should give me alert message.

Comment: Use `&& $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtOther').val() == ''`.

Comment: No, you need to use '===' for string comparison

Comment: @Carter It is only for strict comparison. Anyways, will add that!

Comment: @PraveenKumar: Thanks for your suggestion also. It is working for me, just need to clear the value for the second time if user wants to fill the data.

Comment: Use `val('')` on the textbox or input. :)

Comment: Second time? What does it mean?

Comment: @Saba Check my updated answer. Consider voting up or accepting my answer if worked!

Comment: But when I put other data, and keep unfill the textbox. It stills submits the form

Comment: I mean to say, when I put value in other textboxes and check validations for other. And submit the form with my this textbox empty, it submits the form without any validation messages

Comment: Seems like a small logic issue. Can you show the full code? Update it in the question. Will debug it.

Comment: Do you want JS fiddle for the validations for the other code ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58799/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-and-saba).

Answer (score 1):

Using `val('')` resets the textbox:

```
$('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtOther').val('')
```

I'm assuming you want to check if the value is empty, so use this instead:

```
$('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtOther').val() === ''
```

Comment: @Nadeem How is this answer different from mine, and I have the same one and suddenly you changed your accepted answer from mine to this, I am just curious to know why. `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar: it is not like that. I m sorry for it.